# Corrupt qemu guest memory intentionally

Tags: qemu

Is there is  a way to intentionally corrupt guest memory in qemu to wreak havoc in a system intentionally? Like corrupting windows guest from linux host so far I tried using a custom made software to modify qemu's memory but that didn't work very well after hitting into memory that is used by qemu which causes it to segfault.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the GUI tool [`gameconqueror`](https://manpages.debian.org/gameconqueror/gameconqueror.1) along its backend [`scanmem`](https://manpages.debian.org/scanmem/scanmem.1) which is doing the real work can help for this (upstream source https://github.com/scanmem/scanmem). QEMU maps all of the VM's memory so ptracing QEMU allows to alter such memory.

I tested with a simple case: define a variable with a long string in a bash shell running in a Linux VM, search this string with `gameconqueror` attached to the QEMU process and modify all occurrences (only one of them is really the variable: others are likely various temporary places) of this string found in memory, but keeping the same length, then read back the variable to see that the value was changed.

Now about avoiding to trash QEMU itself, `gameconqueror` might not have direct features for this, but what can be done is figure out what's the VM's mapped memory.

For my previous example, the VM had 1GB and the QEMU's process map (available in `/proc/<pid>/maps`, see [`proc(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/proc.5)) had a single range having exactly 1GB:

```
7f5597e00000-7f55d7e00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

and of course hits were in this range.

So searching first for a `rw-p` (or at least with *perms* starting with `rw-`) range of exactly the VM's size by looking first in `/proc/<pid>/maps` should help figure out the correct zone first and pick hits only in the correct zone: this should affect the VM but not QEMU anymore.